# How it's possible to loop into an infinite generator to remove some items?

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

I recently watched a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jwV3zxXc8E) describing laziness in Python with an example which finds prime numbers.

We got a function which yields a number from an infinite stream of numbers:

```py
def nums(n):
    yield n
    yield from nums(n+1)
```

Nothing fancy here. The part I don't understand is `i for i in s if i%n != 0` in `sieve` function which is in charge of finding the actual prime numbers.

```py
def sieve(s):
    n = next(s)
    yield n
    yield from sieve(i for i in s if i%n != 0)
```

Seems it's creating a new generator passing it to `sieve` function, keeping only the numbers that are not multiples of `n`.

---

My question is that, isn't `s` an infinite stream? How it's possible to loop into all of it to remove necessary numbers creating the new generator?

I guess this part is lazy itself too... Is this `i for i in s if i%n != 0` some kind of one-linear generator that iterate one by one when `next(s)` gets run?

**In short** what I'm getting out of it is that we are refining the generator being passed to `sieve` each time it gets run.

Comment: I guess the answer is "Yes, you're correct"...

Comment: It should really be iterative, not recursive

Comment: @wjandrea How would you make `sieve` iterative?

Comment: @superb [with a list of seen numbers](https://gist.github.com/wjandrea/6322ed8906ef3780311a39b5bcc88825)

Comment: @wjandrea Ok. I was wondering whether you had something closer to the original. I made [this](https://repl.it/repls/MintyUnselfishVaporware#main.py), but that's no good.